# Styling Bootstrap Dropdown Button the same as Anchor inside of a table on Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a dropdown menu & button within a table cell.  This dropdown must contain both anchors and buttons.  I have no control over replacing the button elements with anchors, however, I would like the buttons to look just like standard Bootstrap menu items, so I'm styling them just like the anchors, but something strange is occurring to the width of the items.  The dropdown, when located within a table, will grow to the size of a the biggest Anchor, but not the biggest button.  However, when outside of the table, the dropdown menu grows to the size of the button perfectly.

I've put together a fiddle to show the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/5p341amh/205/

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default"
                        data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span id="dropdown_title2">Select Something</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Fooooooooooo</a></li>
                    <li><button tabindex="-1" href="#">Baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaar</button></li>
                    <li><button tabindex="-1" href="#">Baz</button></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any insight would be great on how to fix this!  Thanks!

Comment: The problem is only appears in Firefox.  Chrome seems to perform as I would expect.

Comment: Found the solution here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14320

Had to change width: 100% to min-width: 100%

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your answer good, but you don't need to add a button element and put the anchor tag in it. You can add the anchor tag only and style it as a button.`<a href="#" id="button" class="btn btn-primary " >Baaaaaaaaaaa</a>`

Comment: Sorry, but I can not use only anchor tags.  :(  The dropdown items are a mix of anchors and buttons that need to look the same.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
display: table;
max-width: 300px /* or set your specified max-width */;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the width of the dropdown has to remain dynamic because it can be customized with any strings.

Comment: then just do "display: table;" or try "overflow: auto"

Comment: Assuming these are for the <button> element.  but adding 'display: table' has no affect and 'overflow: auto' just cuts the text off instead of increasing the menu width.